# Need Help Identifying Mystery Berry

Tags: identification, vines

Anyone know what these berries are? I wasn't able to get a good closeup with my phone, but they have a crevice on one side, similar to the "butt" shape of a peach.

**EDIT**
When I took the original pictures yesterday (just before sunset) it looked like the berries and leaves were coming from the canes, but after closer inspection in full daylight, its clear the vine has just wrapped itself around the black raspberry canes.. sorry for the confusion. I've added some better pictures. Also, I split one open a red one and touched a drop of the juice to the tip of my tongue, it was very bitter, not at all sweet.

[image: Mystery Berry Closer]
[image: Mystery Berry Leaves Closer]

[image: Mystery Berries]
[image: Mystery Berry Bush Leaves]

Comment: That vine looks nothing like a black raspberry cane to me...?

Comment: In the top picture, I can see what looks to be a couple of flowers, but can't see them properly - can you post another photo showing any flowers present on the plant please?

Comment: @Bamboo: To me, the flowers seem to belong to the rubus...

Comment: @Ecnerwal the vines were just wrapped around the canes, see edit. Thanks

Comment: @Bamboo the blurry flowers are actually from the golden rasp behind it in the next pot over. I tried to see if I could find any flowers anywhere on the vine but all I saw were the green/red berries.

Comment: What do the berries smell like when cut open?

Comment: @J.Musser it just smells "weedy", bitter and grassy. There were 5 semi round black seeds inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might have found my answer, it looks like [Bridal Creeper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagus_asparagoides), or at least something closely related to that.